# What is the best SE site to ask a question for describing a generic api?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a good/best SE site to ask a question about the definition a word, in this example: *web-api*?

What I want to know is, is this a good definition of a api (as commonly used in contemporary discussions about api's):

> "*A program running on a server that has an api if it can respond with data -- in a known standardized format such as json or xml (not just a html-web-page) -- to a request written in the form of a URL.*"

Where would I ask this question to get feedback on this?

Comment: [webapps.se] is probably _not_ a good fit. But without a sample of the type of question, there's really no way to be sure.

Comment: Now that you've added a sample, I don't know that there is anywhere in Stack Exchange where that would be on-topic. Perhaps the best place to ask is [Stack Overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @gnat would you please view my response to the point of duplication?

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a good place to look up the meaning of words or acronyms. The site [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) has some recommendations for [dictionary and dictionary like sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools).

I don't think a site that replaces a dictionary or a thesaurus will fly as there are plenty of such sites on the internet already. The English Language & Usage site is not itself a replacement for a dictionary, its [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) warns that

> If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to be of some help. View our [list of community recommended resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) to find some that may be of help to you.
>
> - Try a dictionary if you want to know what a word or phrase means, how it evolved, or how it is pronounced.
> - Try a thesaurus if you want to know words or phrases that have a similar meaning to one you already know.
>
> Of course, if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to ask here on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!